# HttpUrlConnection fetched different content from website content

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

i have tried to fetch the website content from android.

in .NET, it can be done by

```
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(threeROllrl);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
StreamReader vr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string result = vr.ReadToEnd();
```

however, in android, i tried to use

```
URL url = new URL(urlstr);
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(8000 /* milliseconds */);
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(8000 /* milliseconds */);
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConnection.connect();
BufferedReader reader = null;
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
}
```

but it returned different content (in android httpurlconnection, no html content is fetched at all, but the metadata, style and scripts only), i wanna if it is because the response are the mobile version, i want to how retrieve the desktop content of the website in the android httpurlconnection.

after checked, i have found that the android httpurlconnection is actually fetching the header of the website and some bottom content, but it cannot fetch middle body. or it is stopped for some unknown reason (but no error is  found).

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the `User-agent`  header in your http request to be as a desktop

[here is](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent) a list of user agent that you can use

Comment: hi, i have tried to add this line but then the app is stuck in it.//            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36");